# Converting Decimal to Hexadecimal in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex, decimal

1. i am getting answer as 7D while i should be getting 7D0. I actually dont know how to solve it:
2. my test case at the beginning was 31 which answer was correct 1F but as i go towards higher number my code doesnt work.
3. using loops might be more efficient but i am not too comfortable with loop right now
4. please help !!!

   ```
   def dec2hex(n):
   x1 =0
   counter = 0 
   answer = ""
   if n<=0:
       answer =answer + "0"
   else:
       while (n >16):
           counter +=1
           n  =  n /16

           x = n

           if(x <16 ):
               x = int(n)
               break
           else: 
               continue
       if ((n-x) *16 <16 ):
           counter1 = 1
       else:
           counter1 = counter -1
       rem = (n-x) * (16**(counter1))

       if rem >16:
           while (n >16):
               rem = rem /16

               x1 = rem

               if(x1 <16 ):
                   x1 = int(rem)
                   break
               else: 
                   continue
       if n < 10:
           answer =answer + str(int(x))
       if (rem  ==10 or x1 ==10):
           answer = answer + "A"
       if (rem  ==11 or x1 ==11):
           answer = answer + "B"
       if (rem ==12 or x1 ==12):
           answer = answer + "C"
       if (rem  ==13 or x1 ==13):
           answer = answer + "D"
       if (rem  ==14 or x1 ==14):
           answer = answer + "E"
       if (rem  ==15 or x1 ==15):
           answer = answer + "F"
       print(counter,rem,x1,n,counter,x)
   return answer
   ```

   dec2hex(2000)

Comment: If this isn't an exercise, you'd simply want `return f"{n:X}"`

Comment: Note, you *are* using loops. The simplest way would be to accumulate the hexidecimal digits (strings) in a list. Start by successively taking the remainder and appending the corresponding hexi-digit (you could use a *list* for this). Then, reverse the final result and `''.join` itno a string. You really only need a single while-loop

Comment: Note, to get the *remainder* simply use the modulus operator, i.e. `%`, no need for this: `rem = (n-x) * (16**(counter1))` you don't need a `counter`. So, simply put, you could do, `n, rem = n // 16, n % 16`, or use the helper function `divmod`, so `n, rem = divmod(n, 16)`

Comment: I am sorry i  just noticed the mistake in the heading, i need to convert decimal to Hexadecimal no the other way around @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: Yes, that is what I had understood anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The most elegant answer I can think of is to format a string literal and it will convert the value for you

3.6+ (f-strings)

```
>>> d = 2000
>>> print(f'{d:X}')
7D0
```

pre-3.6 (string format function)

```
>>> d = 2000
>>> print('{:X}'.format(d))
7D0
```

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings

https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec

Answer (score 0):

I would like to propose this approach to the problem.
A while loop is used to cycle the main division and the reminder calculus
A for loop is used to invert the final answer string

The while loop condition exclude the case in which 0 is entered becasue the division remainder will be always zero and the loop will be infinite.
In this case the answer will be forced to 0 by the first if.

```
def dec2hex(hexnum):
hexstring = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
counter = 0
remainder = []
answer = ""
if hexnum > 0:
    while hexnum > 0:
        remainder.append(hexnum % 16)
        hexnum = hexnum // 16
        counter = counter + 1
    for reverse in remainder[::-1]:
        answer = answer + hexstring[reverse]
else:
    answer = "0"
return answer
```

print(dec2hex(2000))